# Java form not loading

Tags: java

Any idea why this code at runtime dosen't show the form I've created??
It just simple build the solution but the form doesn't appear.

Form Code:

```
 public class MedForm extends javax.swing.JPanel {

        public MedForm() {
            initComponents();
        }

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            String dbName = txtDBName.getText();
            DBConnect connect = new DBConnect(dbName);
            System.out.println("OK");
        }  

      private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;


private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtDBName;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Main method:

```
public class MedApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // DB1Connect connect = new DBConnect("test");
        //connect.getData();
            MedForm medForm = new MedForm();
           medForm.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: A JPanel is not a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components cannot be directly displayed on the screen, you need to embed them in a `java.awt.Window` to show them.
In **Swing**, you can use either `JFrame` and `JDialog` (both are subclasses of `Window`).

Example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    MedForm medForm = new MedForm();
    frame.setContentPane(medForm);

    frame.setBounds(200, 200, 600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When your form has a **preferred size** (either explicitely set, or implicitely by its layout manager), you can use `frame.pack()` and `frame.setLocation(..)` instead of setting the bounds.

Comment: Great, I just needed a Jframe, so removed the Panel.